# iOS 6 : Scan Wifi Information

Tags: ios6, wifi

I want to retrieve information about the currently available Access points in an IPad app. As far as I learned there is a way to achieve this with a jailbroken device (see [iOS wifi scan, signal strength](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12054818/ios-wifi-scan-signal-strength)).

Since I am using iOS 6, I was wondering if someone knows whether the scanning of wifi information can be done in iOS 6 *without jailbreaking* the device?

Comment: nope you cant. its the limitation of the iOS itself that will not let you do that.