# Wifi Connection in Iphone App

Tags: iphone

How to Check in the app constantly of the signals of wifi connection.In case of less signals has to send notification to server.

Comment: won't wifi auto swap to radio if no signal?

Comment: I have to send notification to server in case of less internet connection

Comment: when connection start getting less .at that point has to send it

Comment: but what if it gets less, and then gets more, and then gets less, ....

Comment: The moment it gets less i have to send the notification

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12054818/ios-wifi-scan-signal-strength and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14532651/how-to-detect-network-signal-strenghth-in-ios-reachability?lq=1 can help you.

Comment: Here you go....

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083701/how-to-check-for-an-active-internet-connection-on-iphone-sdk

Comment: these posts are all of the checking of wifi connections.. i have to check its signals and on less signals has to send notification to server

Comment: You can't check the strength of the WiFi connection using public APIs unless you are transmitting something and counting the bytes. It is also impractical to notify the server given the strength fluctuations. This is just not a good idea.

Comment: ok jano .but i need to that as it is a client requirement.is there any way to do it using public api

Answer (score 0):

To get the status of network you should refer at Apple's sample code Reachability

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html

I think you'll find all you need.