# How to read wifi rssi / signal strength for non-jail break iOS devices.

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, wifi

I want to read wifi rssi / signal strength for non-jail break iOS device. If there is no way using public api. please let me know about any private api doing this.

Comment: Private API usage will result in rejection of your App by Apple.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS wifi scan, signal strength](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12054818/ios-wifi-scan-signal-strength)